# Unable to access server database schemas in mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, macos, ssh

So I'm working in a team and my computer in particular is running into issues that other people's computers aren't running into, so none of us know how to diagnose the issue. I am running on a Mac with El Capitan. These are the steps I took to connect and access the server database:

SSH into server's terminal:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key username@serverIP`

Port forwarding through ssh:
`ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key username@serverIP`

Error: `bind: Address already in use`
I go into System Preferences > mySQL > stop mySQL server instance

I go into mySQL workbench and choose connection method `Standard TCP/IP over SSH`

Enter in all the information and clicked Test Connection and get this popup message:

> Information related to this connection:
>
> Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 3306 User: [username here] SSL: not enabled
>
> A successful MySQL connection was made with the parameters defined for
>   this connection.

My team members were able to see all the database tables that they worked on under the schemas section, but my Schema section shows nothing. What am I missing and why can I not see the schemas despite getting a successful connection message?

Comment: If you haven't already, try running the following into Terminal: `lsof -i tcp:3306`, and report back :)

Comment: COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    8590 username   13u  IPv4 0xff4cf17840c73d6b      0t0  TCP localhost:57836->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    8590 username   14u  IPv4 0xff4cf17843a78673      0t0  TCP localhost:57838->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    8590 username   15u  IPv4 0xff4cf1783b409883      0t0  TCP localhost:57840->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    8590 username   16u  IPv4 0xff4cf1784174ea93      0t0  TCP localhost:57842->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)